# Trouble adding a sequence field to inherited Odoo model

Tags: inheritance, odoo, sequence

Im trying to add a sequence field to the crm.lead model. I have implemented this code for another custom module I built previously with no issues.

Ive added the new field

```
 class vox_crm_register(models.Model):
   
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    name_seq = fields.Char(
        string='Registration Reference',
        required=True,
        copy=False,
        readonly=True,
        index=True,
        default=lambda self: _('New'))
```

Ive overwritten the create function

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        print(vals.get('name_seq'))
        if vals.get('name_seq', _('New')) == _('New'):
            print('IF is true')
            vals['name_seq'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('vox_crm_register.sequence') or _('New')
        res = super(vox_crm_register, self).create(vals)
        return res
```

and this is my sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">

        <record id="registration_sequence" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Registration Sequence</field>
            <field name="code">vox_crm_register.sequence</field>
            <field name="prefix">reg</field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

and heres the view

```
<xpath expr="//sheet/group" position="replace">
     <div class="oe_title">
         <h1><field name="name_seq"/></h1>
     </div>
</xpath>
```

the result from the print statements in the create function  are

None

IF is true

because its inherited do I have to force it in someway or add a context???

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name_seq` is not present in the view definition.

From [constrains](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/api.py#L122) documentation:

> `@constrains` will be triggered only if the declared fields in the decorated method are included in the `create` or `write` call. It implies that fields not present in a view will not trigger a call during record creation.

You can deduct that if the field is not present in a view, its value will not be present in the `create` or `write` method.

***Edit:***

When you click on the Save button, the [saveRecord](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_controller.js#L164) function will be called to return the list of field names whose values have been modified, the same list will be used in the create method.

Since the `name_seq` field is read-only, it will not be present in the create values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry forgot to add the view to my question. Ive updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found the issue, lack of sleep and stupidity. I had changed the code value of the sequence, and did not delete the old sequence from Odoo. As the sequence has the noupdate tag it wouldnt create a new sequence, but also would'nt update. Thanks Kenly for the reply.